# What's the real and correct way to install things in Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, bash, software-installation, environment-variables

I know that I should apt-get things, but I'm asking this for binaries that aren't there, or the ones that I need the latest version. Every time I search about how to install these binaries on Ubuntu, I get different answers. Of course I can just paste the bin into /bin or the directories that are already in my PATH, but lots of apps are full of other files, so that shouldn't be the best way. I often see instructions telling me to add the folder of the app in the PATH, but what would happen if I install like, 100 apps with this technique? Wouldn't my PATH variable get big and messy? Also, I'd be passing this PATH to every app I open, I don't see this as the better way to install things in Linux.

So, which is the right way? Also, if this has something to do with PATH, which is the **correct** way to add paths to the PATH? I always see lots of ways, and I get confused.

I'd like to end this once and for all, because I'm tired of installing things in different ways, and I wanted to do it in the correct and most elegant way.

Comment: The correct way depends on what exactly you're doing. Are you building app from source ? are you using .run or .deb package ? PATH is really for you and your shell so that you can just type in binary name, instead of full path.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install applications in Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/307280/how-do-i-install-applications-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Purpose of PATH variable

`PATH` is meant for your shell - it tells the shell where commands you type in are supposed to live. Good example of that was on OpenSUSE box I once had. On Ubuntu you can type in `iconfig` command and bash will go " oh, I know where that is - i'll run `/sbin/ifconfig`". Well, on OpenSUSE default `PATH` , doesn't have `/sbin` added to it, so `bash` will say "sorry, I don't know where `ifconfig` is , I've no record of such file." So you have to either run `/sbin/ifconfig` ( i.e. full path ) or do it in a smart way - add `/sbin` to `PATH`.

Good example of why you would want to do is when you install custom scripts or binaries. Let's say you have saved something in `/opt/my_stuff` folder , and you want just to call `my_command` by name. Well, you will have to add `/opt/my_stuff` to `PATH`.

#### How to properly add directories to PATH

The basic idea is that you want to *append* or join original `$PATH` with the new directory. As you may or may not know, items in `PATH` variable are delimited with `:`. You also want to `export` the variable, so that other programs ( children of your shell ) know where to look for stuff. All that stuff must happen at the end of `~/.bashrc`, so that when you open shell and it has read your `~/.bashrc` config, it knows where everything is located.

Here's the example from my `~/.bashrc` :

```
export PATH=$PATH:"/opt/microchip/xc16/v1.25/bin"
```

In this case , original `$PATH` will be expanded to a string of directories. We simply add one more to it, and save it back. Nothing complicated.

#### What does this have to do with installing software

If you are installing a file from `.deb` archive or `.run` script, you shouldn't worry about the `PATH` part. It's the responsibility of software author to simplify installation process. Typically, they'll configure their installation to save stuff into one of the common directories that already belong to `PATH`: installation script will say, "hey, install this software into /usr/bin` and you will be able to use it without extra effort.

If software authors install it somewhere that's not typically in `PATH`, they will have to configure your `PATH` variable or you have to do it yourself. In the example above, the directory `/opt/microchip` was created when I was installing Microchip's IDE and compiler. Their installer automatically put that line into my `~/.bashrc`. I often write scripts that go into `/opt` , so I usually mention in the instructions that users have to configure `PATH` themselves.

#### The ~/bin directory

You frequently see people recommending to save script and other types of software into `~/bin`. This folder belongs to you - your user, so if you don't want to share app with other people on  your machine - that's where you'd put it. Difference with `/opt` is that as I mentioned already in a few places  , `/opt` is neutral ground. So if I as system administrator want both my family to also have access to an app with their accounts - that's where I'd put it.

As far as `bash` shell goes, it already handles `~/bin` being added to `PATH` for you. Other shells, like `/bin/sh` , or `tcsh` or `ksh` won't do it, so keep that in mind if you are working on different system or want to use a different shell in your Ubuntu.

#### Addressing specific parts of question

> I often see instructions telling me to add the folder of the app in the PATH, but what would happen if I install like, 100 apps with this technique? Wouldn't my PATH variable get big and messy?

Not really - what's supposed to go into path is directories. If you typically install software in single directory ( such as `~/bin` or `/opt` ) it will require adding only `/opt`. If each software has to live in its own folder under `/opt` , then yes - you'd have to add each and every single one to `PATH`. What you can do , however, is write a script to add all directories to `PATH`. So , let's say:

```
$ for item in /opt/* ; do                                                                                      
 if [ -d "$item" ]; then
     PATH="$PATH:$item"
     echo "$VAR"
 fi
 done
```

And this can live perfectly fine as function at the end of your `~/.bashrc` , so that each time you open the shell, all directories under `/opt` are added automatically.

In my example, I write a lot of scripts. They all live in `~/bin` since all of them are just single files, and there's no need for them to live in separate directories.

> Also, I'd be passing this PATH to every app I open, I don't see this as the better way to install things in Linux.

That's what the `export` variable is for. It passes stuff to child processes of your shell. You as user don't have to do anything. Also, as I mentioned, it's not typically done - software authors create packages that go into directories that are already in `PATH` like `/usr/bin`.

The directories that are not in `/opt` are just a neutral ground and sort of a way for developers to say "hey, our app is 3rd party, so it's not something default."

#### Using GUI apps without PATH variable

Once thing that haven't been covered here is `.desktop` files. To put simply , these are Linux's version of Windows shortcut , but on steroids. Lets say I've build a GUI app in python, and I want it to live in `/opt` folder, but I don't want user to call it from command line - I want them to use a nice and neat desktop shortcut. Well, that's where `.desktop` files come into play. Here's an example:

```
$ cat /home/xieerqi/.local/share/applications/vivaldi.desktop                                                  
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=周迅 mv - YouTube
Icon=vivaldi
Path=/home/xieerqi
Exec=/opt/vivaldi/vivaldi-bin --ppapi-flash-path --ppapi-flash-version --always-authorize-plugins --enable-npapi --no-first-run
StartupNotify=false
StartupWMClass=Vivaldi
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
X-UnityGenerated=true
```

While `vivaldi` app lives happily in `/opt` without ever needing to be referenced in `PATH` , I can use a `.desktop` shortcut to launch it. Again, you'd need to manually create one for each and every app, but as you can guess  Linux has scripting ways to automate even that.

#### Conclusion

So what is the real and correct way to install software on Linux ? There is none, just like there isn't a way on Windows or Mac OS X. Your Windows app could be single `.exe` or a folder with `.exe` and live perfectly fine in `C:\` folder. Same here - on Linux you can have a script or whole suite of software live in `/opt`, or `~/bin` or wherever you choose. The choices , of course, must to some extend be justified. Do you want the app to be available to `root` only, to you `only` , or shared ? Do you want it to be accessible via just its name, or do you want to type in full path to the app ?

#### Additional information

- [Difference between installation of ubuntu software center and command line](https://askubuntu.com/a/826037/295286)

Comment: Yes, usually I just run the .deb, but in lots of cases, they only offer binaries, like in gradle for example, and I have to add it to my path, so I wonder what will happen when I have like 100 apps in the path, it'll get messy, this should not be the right way. Also, about /opt: I used to install apps there, like Telegram, then I noticed that telegram wouldn't ever update itself because that folder had permissions that my user hasn't. Is it good to install things there?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs I'm actually slowly editing my  answer to address some parts of your question. `/opt` is good place to save software -it's sort of neutral ground. Binaries don't usually update themselves, so i don't think this has to do anything with permissions. But yes, `/opt` is owned by root. Again, there's no really right or wrong answer - it depends on what you're doing

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs ok, i think I'm done editing. Please let me know if you have other questions.  There's no voodoo or magic involved in installing software in linux - there are specific decisions to be made, and each of them has purpose. I hope I sufficiently have addressed that.

Comment: well, it would be good to respect the [FHS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard)...! -- for self-updating (without root-permissions) your home-folder would be the only choice... but this is not really recommended!

Comment: @DJCrashdummy  True, that would be better to respect the hierarchy , but it's not always possible.  I personally see self-updating is sort of security hole , which is probably main reason why it's frowned upon. That's one. Second, if you're an administrator of your machine , then you probably do need to assume certain level of responsibility and actually use those root permissions. That's one of the things I dislike about the Windows world - people want to "drive" the machine without being "the driver" and assume responsibility

Comment: The idea of automatically adding all the subdirectories is good! And I understood everything, thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer: What follows below is my personal opinion.**

In Ubuntu, the `~/.profile` has:

```
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

which means if the `~/bin` directory is present, add that to the `PATH`, at start.

So one should put all the user executables in `~/bin` directory, this assures:

- Maintainability
- Cleanliness
- User specific `PATH`

Also, if there exists some executables that can not be put in there, you could easily create a symbolic link on this directory that refers to that executable.

Comment: So the best way you think should be to add all apps in like, /home/Apps, and create symlinks to them in /home/bin?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs You app can reside anywhere, but the executables _can_ be symlinked on `/home/USERNAME/bin/` directory.